# Operation not permitted while executing brew install libimobildevice in mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, libimobiledevice

Im trying to install libimobiledevice with brew install libimobiledevice in my mac but I give operation not permitted error and permission denied. Im admin.

```
cp: utimes: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/.: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried installing it with `--HEAD`

```
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice -g
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, i got the error when openssl is installing, i tried to install openssl and i got the same error. I think this is the problem, the openssl.